# Blend Error When Creating a Data Binding

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I'm getting the following error when I' try to Create a Data Binding for anything:

[image]

> Could not load The assembly Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Design
>   because the following erros occurred: Inheritance security rules
>   violated by type.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with the SDK installation. The error is not in your code.
Try to reinstall it.

Comment: It's been a while since I installed it. I'll try again.

Comment: Neither the VS Update nor the package re-install did any good. The error doesn't seem to be preventing me from working though. Its just a nuisance.